# nativescript - You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file

Tags: typescript, webpack, nativescript, loader

I keep getting this error when I do tns prepare ios.
I feel like it was working before but at some point, it stopped working and throw that error message.
It seems like it's looking for loader but I am not sure how I can configure that.
any idea?

[image]

this is my webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = (env) => {
    webpack.init(env);

    // Learn how to customize:
    // https://docs.nativescript.org/webpack

    return webpack.resolveConfig();
};
```

this is my pakage.json

```
  "name": "@nativescript/template-hello-world-ng",
  "main": "src/main.ts",
  "version": "8.0.5",
  "author": "NativeScript Team <oss@nativescript.org>",
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public"
  },
  "files": [
    "App_Resources",
    "hooks",
    "src",
    "tools",
    "!tools/assets",
    ".editorconfig",
    "references.d.ts",
    "tsconfig.json"
  ],
  "keywords": [
    "nativescript",
    "mobile",
    "angular",
    "{N}",
    "template"
  ],
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "^11.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "^11.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.2.11",
    "@angular/router": "^11.2.11",
    "@nativescript/angular": "~11.8.0",
    "@nativescript/core": "^8.0.2",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~3.0.1",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-snackbar": "^2.1.0",
    "nativescript-clipboard": "^2.1.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.7",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.2.11",
    "@nativescript/ios": "8.0.0",
    "@nativescript/types": "^8.0.1",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "beta",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^11.2.10",
    "typescript": "~4.0.0"
  },
  "private": "true",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "scripts": {
    "ip11": "tns run ios --device 'iPhone 11'"
  }
}
```

and this is my tsconfig.json

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es2017",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["src/*"],
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/tests/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.ios.ts", "src/**/*.android.ts"],
  "files": ["./src/main.ts", "./references.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "platforms", "e2e"]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A pull request and patch update was just published for this with:
@nativescript/core **8.0.3**

See here:
https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/pull/9354

Just be sure your project is using:

```
@nativescript/core: ~8.0.0
```

Then: `ns clean`

Answer (score 0):

It was nothing to do with webpack.
For some reasons, my @nativescript/core was removed.
So, I just had to do `npm i @nativescript/core`

Comment: I'm getting the same error, migrating my app from 6.5 to 8.0.2. Did you do anything else, because the @nativescript/core package isn't removed here. Doesn't look like you where missing it either since it finds the ./node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/index.js file